# How to create a simple animation on ng-repeat?

Tags: javascript, angularjs

I am using angularJS 1.2.28

Here is the source code:

```
<!DOCTYPE html>
<html>
<head>
<style>
.animate-enter {
    -webkit-transition: 1s linear all; /* Chrome */
    transition: 1s linear all;
    opacity: 0;
}
.animate-enter.animate-enter-active {
    opacity: 1;
}
</style>
  <script src="js/angular.min.js"></script>
  <script src="js/angular-animate.min.js"></script>
</head>

<body>
<div ng-app="" ng-controller="performersController">
<p><input type="search" ng-model="username" ></p>
    they are:  {{performers.length}} performers

<ul ng-animate="'animate'" ng-repeat="performer in performers | filter:username">
  <li> 
    {{ (performer.username | uppercase) + ', ' + performer.id }}
    <img ng-src="{{performer.thumb}}"/>
  </li>

</ul>

</div>

<script>
function performersController($scope, $http) {
    $http.get("ajax.php", {
        params:{
            "action":"search", "order":"username", "ethnicty":"", "keyword":""
        }
    }).success(function(data) {
        $scope.performers = data;
    });
}
</script>

</body>
</html>
```

1) Animation NEVER occurs: how to add animation ?
(Do I need to include angular-animate.min.js or is this module included in angularsjs lib ?)

2) this script works with angular 1.2 but gives an error with 1.3: why ?
Error: [ng:areq]

Any idea ?

Comment: You may have a look at this [example](https://docs.angularjs.org/api/ng/directive/ngRepeat#example).

Comment: You need to include the module.